# How can I get an exact result from multiplication that doesn't play nicely in binary?

Tags: math, binary, rounding

Example:
int myNumber = 3;
System.out.print(myNumber*.1);

My output is 0.30000000000000004. My understanding of this is that numbers that don't terminate in binary (e.g. .1 in decimal does not terminate in binary) cause this. However, if I use my calculator, it will simply return 0.3. Is it just rounding?

Comment: I'm assuming it's just rounding the value to be displayed, not the internal representation of the value. It might also be using a BigNum-style representation to store the exact value, but I assume that's less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Simple pocket calculators will often use base 10 arithmetic internally, so the behavior you are seeing is not due to rounding. The reason modern CPUs use base 2 is that it is a more efficient representation for the massive amount of computing throughput they need to handle. But a simple pocket calculator only needs to perform computations as quickly as the human using it enters them. Since base 10 is more appropriate for financial or monetary computations (see for example [C#'s `decimal` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)), that is natural to use in a simple pocket calculator.